# Segmentation Fault when accessing a struct

Tags: c++, templates, segmentation-fault, containers, doubly-linked-list

I have a header file where I define methods. I am ultimately trying to implement a doubly linked list to store data of pairs.
this is cont.h

```
template <class Key, class T> class storage;

template < class Key, class T, class Compare = std::less<Key> > 
class cont{
    private:
        storage <Key, T> data;
    public:
        typedef size_t size_type;
        typedef Key key_type;
        typedef T mapped_type;

        //default constructor
        cont(){}

        cont(key_type k, mapped_type m)
        {
            std::pair<Key, T> x = std::make_pair(k,m);
            data.begin_list(x);

            //std::pair<Key, T> a = std::make_pair(k,m);
            //data.push(a);
        }



};

template <class Key, class T>
struct node
{
    node *prev, *next;
    std::pair<Key, T> node_data;
};

template <class Key, class T>
class storage{
    private:
        node <Key, T> *head;
        node <Key, T> *tail;
        node <Key, T> *curr;
        int size;
    public:
        //default ctor
        storage(){}

        void begin_list(std::pair <Key, T> h)
        {
            size=1;
                    //bottom two lines induce segmentation fault
            //head->node_data=h;
            //head->prev=NULL;

        }

};
```

main.cc will look like this:

```
#include "cont.h"
int main() {
    cont<double, int> s(6.6, 3);
}
```

I don't understand why I get segfault. Should I be dynamically allocating memory for each node?

Comment: 'Should I be dynamically allocating memory for each node?' Of course you should.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `head` has not been initialized by the time `begin_list` gets executed, so dereferencing it gives you undefined behavior:

```
    void begin_list(std::pair <Key, T> h)
    {
        size=1;

        head->node_data=h; // <= DEREFERENCING head WITHOUT HAVING INITIALIZED IT
        head->prev=NULL; // <== SAME HERE
    }
```

Here you probably meant to dynamically allocate an object of type `node` in the constructor of `storage`, assigning the result of the corresponding `new` expression to `head` (and then making `tail` and `curr` point to the same object.

However, please consider *not* using `new`, `delete`, and raw pointers for memory management purposes. Prefer using smart pointers to express ownership.